# Nested NSUserDefaults arrays read/write

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, nsuserdefaults

I have the following structure of data:

```
- Cards
 -- Item 0
  --- Name: Card Name
  --- Number: Card Number
  --- Type: Card Type
 -- Item 1
  --- Name: Card Name
  --- Number: Card Number
  --- Type: Card Type
...
```

The user can add as many cards as he wants, so Name, Number and Type are user defined.

1st question is, how can I write this data to a NSUserDefauls (nested like this)

2nd Question is, and how can I retrieve this data and show the name of each card in a table view. (I already have the tableview set and working, so it's a matter of getting the data from the NSUserDefaults).

Any code example is well appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create this structure is quite simple, you create a dictionary that has an array value for your key `Cards'. Example below..

```
NSMutableDictionary *cards = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *cardArray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSMutableDictionary *item = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[item setValue:@"Card Name" forKey:@"Name"];
[item setValue:@"Card Number" forKey:@"Number"];
[item setValue:@"Card Type" forKey:@"Type"];

[cardArray addObject:item];
[cards setValue:cardArray forKey:@"Cards"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:cards forKey:@"user_cards"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In order to retrieve your cards, you would do something like..Assuming self.cards is an NSMutableArray ivar..

```
NSMutableDictionary *stored = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"user_cards"];

self.cards = [stored valueForKey:@"Cards"];
```

Your tableview should use `cards` ivar to populate your data, like below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    ...... 

    //Now we populate each row of the cell with each `card` Name.
  cell.textLabel.text = [[self.cards objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"Name"];

   .....
}
```

To resave any newly added cards to your stored dictionary you would do something like this..

```
NSMutableDictionary *newCard = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[newCard setValue:@"Card Name" forKey:@"Name"];
[newCard setValue:@"Card Number" forKey:@"Number"];
[newCard setValue:@"Card Type" forKey:@"Type"];

[self.cards addObject:newCard];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"user_cards"] setValue:self.cards forKey:@"Cards"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

If this has helped with your questions, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Just a little extra help, how can I save the new cards without overwriting them?

Comment: Mark this as an answer if its the correct one. To save new cards you can add new objects to self.cards and reset the NSUserDefaults stored value for Cards key.

Comment: yep, the logics of the saving I get it, but since I'm still crawling with obj-c I'm not really sure how to do that :)

Comment: I edited my answer and included example on saving the cards to active array you're using and the stored object.

Comment: in your example, `[self.cards addObject:newCard];` self.cards would be a NSMutableArray and newCard a NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Yes. Same as I did with the initial example of the `item` dictionary. Edited answer again to show initialization of newCard.

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"user_cards"] setValue:self.cards forKey:@"Cards"];` was only saving the first time, all the others were not. so I had to change to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.cards forKey:@"Cards"];`. Now it's working like a charm. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

save

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSArray
[prefs setObject:myArray forKey:@"keyToLookupArray"];

[prefs synchronize];
```

Retrieving

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSArray
NSArray *myArray= [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupArray"];
```